# Does Ruby have a console perf tool like Python does?

Tags: ruby, performance

I am not sure of the name, but in Python I remember seeing how people test the performance of a given method in a module.

In console, they just call them method, tell it how many times to run it, and it keeps track of runtime etc.

does ruby have anything simliar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one called Ruby benchmark:

> http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/classes/Benchmark.html
>   main page: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html

Comment: An additional sibling tool to using benchmark is the [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/) profiler. Benchmark is good for testing a subset of code, and the profiler is good for looking at the entire body of code and finding what is slow or fast or using more memory. Benchmark is great when testing variations on an algorithm. Sometimes we assume a certain algorithm will be fast but don't really know and benchmarks let us find out.